# Is block contains any field which directly give me transaction fees in geth server. if not how i can calculate it?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using geth server for transaction. After transaction is done i got new block but this block not having any field like transaction fees. So my confused about that is block having any field which gives me transaction fees or i have to calculate it manually. If its calculated manually then what is the right formula to calculate transaction fees and how to convert it into ether.

When i google for transaction fees I found two formulas to calculate transaction fees.

1. gas * gasPrice = transacrion fees.
2. gasUsed * gasPrice = transaction fees.

But gas and gasUsed are two different fields which have different values. So I am confused which formula is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention if you are using `web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)` or `web3.getTransactionReceipt(hash)`.

Have a look at this: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt

Notice that it can't get you the receipt until the transaction is mined, then it can give you `gasUsed`.

`gasUsed` * `gasPrice` is the cost in Ether. `gasPrice` is probably something your client already knows since it would have sent it with the transaction. If this is not convenient, you can use `web3.getTransaction(hash)` to find that detail.

The `gasPrice` is a property of the transaction that was signed and sent, while the `gasUsed` is reported when the transaction is mined and run. It's a little confusing because there is also a `gas` parameter sent with the transaction and reported by `getTransaction()`. That is the amount of gas provided by the sender to *potentially* be used. It's not a factor in the final cost of the transaction because unused `gas` is returned to the sender.

Since sending a transaction, getting a hash and waiting for the transaction to be mined is such a common pattern, this might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6

Hope it helps.